# hostfile.json webroot property not serving static files

Tags: asp.net-core

Going nuts :-)

I've installed the latest ASP.NET Core (RC2).

I'd like to be able to create a `*.sln`, with multiple `*.csproj`: one for server side development, and one for just client side development.

The reason we are keeping them separate is so that we can have the option of giving the the clientside `*.csproj` to external developers with better UI skills to work on without needing to know much about the server side code. They could work on the client side html/js using Visual Studio Code or other light weight IDE, and not requiring Visual Studio to get involved.

In the client `*.csproj`, I'd like to serve static files (html/js/css) for an angular project *from the root directory*, not from the *wwwroot* directory, so that gulpfile.js relative paths, etc are identical to how one would set up an angular project without Visual Studio.

As I understand it, the rules are now:
 * use the webroot setting in hosting.json if hosting.json file exists.
 * otherwise, use wwwroot.
 * if that's missing, use root.
 * See: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/450

First, checked that I had set up static page routing. Created a wwwroot/index.html page. Tada! Works.

Now, renamed the directory to `app/` and updated `hosting.json` to point to it. After a reload of the project, the `app/` folder changed icon..good...run...no joy. Fight with it for a while. No success...

Then delete the `app/` folder and `hosting.json` file altogether. End up definitely wanting to throw something...

The only way I'm getting static files is if the folder is called `wwwroot`. Whether I have a `hosting.json` file or not.

That's contrary to the documentation at: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/450

Has anybody else succeeded in getting rid of the wwwroot folder? If so...how?!?!?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you *can* open up the root of your ASP.NET Core app for serving static files, it's not a good idea because once you do, there's nothing preventing someone from navigating to project.json or any other file in the root.

That being said, here's how you would go about serving up static files outside of wwwroot.

First, create a static class that returns IApplicationBuilder.  In here you will define what physical path to make accessible along with an optional URL re-write of that path (see comments in the code):

```
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRootResources(this IApplicationBuilder app, HostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath); // WARNING - this opens up the root of the app
        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "static"); // this would allow for serving up contents in a physical path folder named 'static'
        var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path);

        var options = new StaticFileOptions();
        // the below line re-writes the path name of the physical path, it can have the string value of anything you want to call it
        options.RequestPath = ""; //  in this example, an empty string will give the *appearance* of it being served up from the root
        //options.RequestPath = "/static"; // this will use the URL path named static, but could be any made-up name you want
        options.FileProvider = provider;

        app.UseStaticFiles(options);
        return app;
    }
}
```

Next, in the Startup.cs, call that function from the Configure method:

```
app.UseRootResources((HostingEnvironment)env);
```

Now you can serve up static files outside of wwwroot!  Referencing the static file in HTML will use the path you defined in the Options.RequestPath as set in the ApplicationBuilderExtensions class.  Assuming you left the RequestPath to an empty string to simulate the root, you then call the resource like it lived there (even though it really lives in the 'static' folder) thanks to the magic of URL re-writing:

```
<img src="bus.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I think I've come around to understanding why opening up the root folder is *not* best practices. 

Thanks for the 'how' though. Learnt quite a bit.

Comment: Microsoft has now released documentation about working with static files in ASP.NET Core: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html